# Arrow function never being converted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

Below is configuration i have: Here dependencies contains all the library names in my project's packageJson file.

```
var dependencies = Object.keys(packageJson && packageJson.dependencies || {});
    gulp.task('init', function() {
        return browserify()
            .require(dependencies)
            .transform('babelify', {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react',"stage-0"],
                plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-es2015-arrow-functions']
            })
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('libs.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('server/public/dist'));
    });
```

Now the issue is there is plugin named: **object.intersect** it has below code:
Notice **...rest** and **=>** and this is not working for IE only it works fine on chrome & FF.

```
function intersect (...rest) {
.....
  if (rest.length === 1) return rest[0] || {}

  // step 1
  const keysList = rest.map(obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj)
  })
....
}
```

So that I am trying plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-es2015-arrow-functions'] but in my lib.js file its never get converted. Please let me know what am i missing?

Comment: @Teemu - assuming that is what transform-es2015-arrow-functions should then handle, no?

Comment: Your [stage-0 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-0.html) should take care of this, since it contains everything from `stage-3`, which contains `rest/spread`. Very odd.

Comment: Yea that is my query I don't know what am i missing? I am trying it for last 4 hours but no luck transform-es2015-arrow-functions should transform fat arrows right?

Comment: @Tholle should I try with stage-3?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, since `stage-0` contains everything `stage-3` contains.

Comment: Which babel version? It seems that `es2015 preset` has been replaced with [env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015) and `es2015 preset` already contains `transform-es2015-arrow-functions` plugin.

Comment: it's "babel@6.23.0"

Comment: Guys any update?